# Method of partial fraction decomposition for fractional power

Tags: fractions, partial-fractions

Can we decompose

$\frac{1}{(\sqrt{s}+1)(s^{2}+1)} = \frac{A}{\sqrt{s}+1} + \frac{Bs+C}{s^{2}+1}?$

I think the method of partial fraction decomposition will not work here due to fractional power in the denominator. Is there way to decompose it?

Comment: If you substitute $t=\sqrt{s}$ the usual partial fractions will work.  Then you can substitute back.  You can decide of you want complex factors or not.

Comment: Thanks, this substitution will work.